# Categorized Photo Albums

Tags: beginner, swift, ios, mobile

I was told the function "hompage" was too clunky to conveniently make a tableview. The cells will have the information in "PHOTO ALBUM ICONS" and "BUTTON ON TOP OF PHOTO ALBUM ICONS".

```
import UIKit
import Cartography
import ChameleonFramework

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

    //DECLORATION OF TABLEVIEW

    var albumTable = UITableView()

    //DECLORATION OF TITLE

    var catalogs = UILabel()


    //DECLORATION OF ALBUM BUTTON ICONS

    var button: UIImage = UIImage (named: "AlbumButton")!

    var album1:UIImageView!
    var album2:UIImageView!
    var album3:UIImageView!
    var album4:UIImageView!

    //DECLORATION OF BUTTONS ON TOP OF ICON

    var button1 = UIButton()
    var button2 = UIButton()
    var button3 = UIButton()
    var button4 = UIButton()

    //DECLORATION OF CAMERA BUTTON ICON

    var camLabel = UILabel() //SNAP IT!
    var camera: UIImage = UIImage (named: "Camera")!
    var camera1:UIImageView!
    var button5 = UIButton()//CLEAR BUTTON COVERING CAMERA ICON AND LABEL


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        homePage()

        //TABLEVIEW

        albumTable.delegate  =  self
        albumTable.dataSource  = self
        albumTable.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    //FUNCTION FOR MAINPAGE VIEWS

    func homePage() {

        //BACKGROUND COLOR

        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.flatPowderBlueColor()

        //TITLE

        self.view.addSubview(catalogs)
        self.catalogs.text = "MY ALBUMS"
        self.catalogs.font = UIFont(name: "ChalkboardSE-Bold", size: 28)
            self.catalogs.textAlignment = .Center}

        //PHOTO ALBUM ICONS

        album1 = UIImageView()
        album1.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
        album2 = UIImageView()
        album2.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
        album3 = UIImageView()
        album3.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
        album4 = UIImageView()
        album4.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill

        album1.image = button
        album2.image = button
        album3.image = button
        album4.image = button

        /*album1.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        album2.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        album3.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        album4.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()*/

        self.view.addSubview(album1)
        self.view.addSubview(album2)
        self.view.addSubview(album3)
        self.view.addSubview(album4)

        //BUTTON ON TOP OF PHOTO ALBUM ICONS


        self.button1.setTitle("BUGS", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        //button1.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        self.view.addSubview(button1)

        self.button2.setTitle("COOKING", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        //button2.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        self.view.addSubview(button2)

        self.button3.setTitle("CARS", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        //button3.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        self.view.addSubview(button3)

        self.button4.setTitle("BIRDS", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        //button4.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        self.view.addSubview(button4)

        // CAMERA ICON


        camera1 = UIImageView()
        camera1.image = camera
        camera1.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
        self.view.addSubview(camera1)
        //camera1.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

        //CAMERA BUTTON

        self.button5.setTitle("", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        //button5.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        self.view.addSubview(button5)

        //CAMERA LABEL

        self.camLabel.text = "SNAP IT!"
        self.camLabel.font = UIFont(name: "ChalkboardSE-Regular", size: 16)
        self.camLabel.textAlignment = .Center
        self.view.addSubview(camLabel)



        //ARRAY FOR ALL VIEWS ON 1ST PAGE

        let views:[UIView] = [catalogs, album1, album2, album3, album4, button1, button2, button3, button4, camera1, button5, camLabel]

        //CONSTRAINTS FOR ALL VIEWS ON FIRST PAGE

        constrain(views) { (_views) in

            //HEADING CONTRAITS

            _views[0].height == 50
            _views[0].width == 210
            _views[0].top == (_views[0].superview?.top)! + 20
            _views[0].centerX == (_views[0].superview?.centerX)!

            //ALBUM IMAGEVIEW CONSTRAINTS

            _views[1].height == 180
            _views[1].width == 180
            _views[1].top == (_views[1].superview?.top)! + 55
            _views[1].left == (_views[1].superview?.left)! + 0

            _views[2].height == 180
            _views[2].width == 180
            _views[2].top == (_views[2].superview?.top)! + 55
            _views[2].right == (_views[2].superview?.right)! + 0

            _views[3].height == 180
            _views[3].width == 180
            _views[3].top == (_views[1].bottom) + 0
            _views[3].left == (_views[3].superview?.left)! + 0

            _views[4].height == 180
            _views[4].width == 180
            _views[4].top == (_views[2].bottom) + 0
            _views[4].right == (_views[4].superview?.right)! + 0

            //BUTTONS ON TOP OF IMGAGEVIEW CONSTRAINTS

            _views[5].height == 60
            _views[5].width == 82
            _views[5].top == (_views[1].top) + 50
            _views[5].left == (_views[5].superview?.left)! + 53.2

            _views[6].height == 60
            _views[6].width == 82
            _views[6].top == (_views[2].top) + 50
            _views[6].right == (_views[5].superview?.right)! - 46.5

            _views[7].height == 60
            _views[7].width == 82
            _views[7].top == (_views[1].bottom) + 50
            _views[7].left == (_views[5].superview?.left)! + 53.2

            _views[8].height == 60
            _views[8].width == 82
            _views[8].top == (_views[2].bottom) + 50
            _views[8].right == (_views[5].superview?.right)! - 46.5

            //CAMERA ICON CONSTRAINTS

            _views[9].height == 100
            _views[9].width == 130
            _views[9].bottom == (_views[9].superview?.bottom)! - 60
            _views[9].centerX == (_views[9].superview?.centerX)!

            //CAMERA BUTTON CONSTRAINTS

            _views[10].height == 150
            _views[10].width == 130
            _views[10].bottom == (_views[9].superview?.bottom)! - 20
            _views[10].centerX == (_views[9].superview?.centerX)!

            //CAMERA LABEL CONSTRAINTS

            _views[11].height == 20
            _views[11].width == 80
            _views[11].bottom == (_views[11].superview?.bottom)! - 47
            _views[11].centerX == (_views[11].superview?.centerX)!


        }


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

A few things I noticed:

1. You have: `var button1 = UIButton()`
   and so on in some places, but `var x: Type` in others.

   It seems to me better to just do `var button1: UIButton`.
   This way, the compiler will yell at you if you forget to instantiate /    assign it. (It's basically free error checking).

   Obviously if you have a default value you want to assign, then do it. But here, you are just instantiating an empty UIButton--that will only crash your program if you forget to assign it.
2. You call `homePage()` before it's defined... I know that this is technically OK, but it causes you to jump around in the code when trying to read it from top-to-bottom. This can subconsciously make your program more difficult to understand / maintain, since most people learn to program "procedurally".

   I think most people don't do this stringently, but to me, at least, I'm like "WTF is homePage()?" Then I have to scroll down to see it, then scroll back up, while trying to keep everything sorted in my head.
3. Some of your spacing is a bit inconsistent.. I know it can be a pain (especially in Xcode). But at times you are ending a block with one empty line, then a comment, then two empty lines, and other times you end a block with two empty lines, a comment, then one empty line.

   Something like this could be better:

   ```
   // DO STUFF

   math().do().moreMath()

   // DO MORE MATH

   math().do().moreMath()
   ```

   Or:

   ```
   // Mathtime!:

   math().do()
   math().do()


   // Recess time!

   recess().do()
   ```

There is also what appears to be a bug that I fixed˚:

```
func homePage() {

    //BACKGROUND COLOR

    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.flatPowderBlueColor()

    //TITLE

    self.view.addSubview(catalogs)
    self.catalogs.text = "MY ALBUMS"
    self.catalogs.font = UIFont(name: "ChalkboardSE-Bold", size: 28)
    self.catalogs.textAlignment = .Center
```

Fixing that requires you to put another `}` at the very bottom.

Also, I'm not 100% on this, as it appears to be a method in another API, `constrain(views) { (_views) in` but a simple block might be easier:

```
constrainViews: do {

    //HEADING CONSTRAITS

    views[0].height == 50
```

Hope this helps some!

Comment: I actually just made a collection view instead. It made it A LOT easier. Thanks